# Do clients normally send http headers

Tags: networking, http-headers, system-administration

Just a quick question, and probably a stupid one.

But usually when a client connects to an http server, the server sends them the header and the html, correct?

I'm packet sniffing a realtime-chat, and attempting to reverse engineer a plain text protocol, and it's connected to a http server. This is why I ask, for verification.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is correct. Anyways, you have to differentiate between for example GET and POST Requests.

While POST Requests normally have a "real" body with information that they are delivering to the Server, the body of GET Requests is empty for most of the time.

For the responses, your Claim is correct. The Header is sent to tell how big the response is, which MIME Type is used, etc.